# In order to add new functionality to existing Firefox clients, do I need to create an extension or a plugin?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, npapi

More specifically, the idea is to allow the user to open Firefox, highlight a word on a web page, right click on it, and have an additional option that, when selected, calls c++ code that does something with the input string (must call C++ code, unfortunately), and displays a dialog box showing the result.

I'm still not sure if in order to implement this functionality I need to create a Firefox plugin or an extension. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Also, if someone can show me sample code in order to get me started that would be appreciated. (XPCOM, which I'm not even sure is what I should be using, seems a bit complicated for this seemingly simple project.)

Comment: Worth reading: [Browser plugins vs. Extensions - the difference](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a regular Firefox extension. It can [add an item to the context menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions#Modifying_the_context_menu), NPAPI plugins cannot do this. When it is clicked it can [get the selected text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) and send it to your binary library. The best way to call functions in this library is [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes), XPCOM is not required.